# How to put jQuery variable to a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to give a jQuery variable to a PHP variable when document is ready. What I have is a list with all sort of values with different links, which I get by an external website via cURL. With jQuery I am getting the value's by the href link. So what I want is when document is ready with loading, then it should give the jQuery variable to a php variable and echo it.

What I have so far:

```
//Javascript.js
$(document).ready(function() {
var value = $("a[href='index.php?p=trading&m=42&b=BTC']:eq(3)").text();
 $.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: "get",
    data: value,
    success: function(){
        alert("success");
        alert(value);
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
});

alert(value);   
});
```

The output of value = 55.0

```
<a href="index.php?p=trading&m=42&b=BTC">55.0</a> //from cURL page
<!-- index.php -->
<?php
$a = $_GET['value'];
if($_GET['value'] == "")
{
    echo("empty");
}
else {
    echo($a);
}
?>
```

The GET/POST is success, but it doesn't show up at the php page. Hope anyone got a solution for this.

Comment: and where should the output of `echo` be? within the same page you are calling the `ajax` function?

Comment: Yes, if that is possible when the page is ready with loading

Comment: `data: value,` is what's being passed to the PHP file, you need a response object like the answer below which will hold what's _returned_ from the PHP file

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
data: value,
success: function(){
    alert("success");
    alert(value);
},
```

to this:

```
data: "value=" + value,
success: function(response){
    alert("success");
    alert(response);
},
```

You need to capture the response(echo) from the `index.php` file and alert that.

ADDITIONAL INFO: After seeing the whole index.php file

Put this block at the top of your PHP file, not the bottom:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['value'] == "")
    {
        echo "empty";
    }
    else {
        echo $_POST['value'] ;
    }
    exit;
?>
```

And add the `exit;` at the end like above.

When you call this php file via ajax, you do not want to execute the rest of the php file, only the part in the `if $_GET` block. So this needs to be at the top of the file with exit after it so the rest doesn't get executed when it is a `$_GET` request.

Comment: also note he hasn't set a variable in `data:value` meaning , the url will look like this , if value is say 55.0 index.php?55.0. so it should be something like this `data: "value="+value`

Comment: That response is giving me the whole source of the page

Comment: @Jordy144 The whole source of what page?

Comment: I don't see any point in the response. What I want is that PHP gets the jQuery value, and echo it.

Comment: I also get the message Undefined index: value in index.php, it seems that it can't get the value

Comment: @Jordy144 You are using ajax. PHP is echoing it, but you need jQuery to display it. Hence capturing the "echo" from the PHP file and alerting it.

Comment: @Jordy144 That means that `$_GET['value']` isn't set. Are you sure `value` has something in it when you send it via ajax?

Comment: @Superphonic yes, it shows me the right value (55.00) in the alert. But I think what I want is not possible, because the jQuery checks the value when page is loaded. I literally searched a few days to get this fixed lol

Comment: What you want to do is definitely possible. Have you changed the data line is the ajax call to `data: "value=" + value,`

Comment: Yes I did, please take a look at my index.php -> http://pastebin.com/m0vMvQ7G   and the jQuery code above is my javascript.js. I really don't know what I am doing wrong, since the ajax process seems to be good

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49569/discussion-between-jordy144-and-superphonic)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var value = $("a[href='index.php?p=trading&m=42&b=BTC']:eq(3)").text();
 $.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: "post",
    data: "value="+value,
    success: function(result){
        alert("success");
        alert(result);
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
});

alert(result); 
});


index.php

$a = $_POST['value'];
if($_POST['value'] == "")
{
    echo "empty";
}
else {
    echo $a ;
}
```

Comment: I did not vote you down, but it's not working. Please take a look at my index.php http://pastebin.com/m0vMvQ7G

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result by changing  `data:value` to `data:{"value":value}`

Thanks